# ViewControllers, memory consumption and code efficiency

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, memory-management, uiviewcontroller

My app has the following layout/flow:

[image]

**LandingVC**: The page a new user will see when first runs the app. This page will explain what the app is for and has 2 buttons: Login and Register

**LoginVC**: Where the user will use his/her email and password to log in

**RegisterVC**: Where the user will use his/her email and password to register

**MainVC**: A tab bar view controller where the user will be redirected if:

- user registers successfully for the first time
- user logs in successfully
- user is logged in

If the user is not logged in he/she should be redirected to LandingVC.

The way I am handling it is as follows:

In appDelegate.swift I check whether the user is logged in or not.

[image]

If the user is logged in I set the **MainVC** as the **root controller**.

If the user is not logged in, then i set the **LandingVC** as the **root controller**.

**QUESTION A:**
Everything work just fine but since I am fairly new to iOS development I worry if the way I present/push/dismiss ViewControllers is the correct one in terms of memory consumption and code efficiency. What do you think? Do I get it all wrong or am I in the right path?

To measure it I followed the procedure below:

Run the app in **iOS Simulator** using **iPhone X**. The user is initially not logged in so I used the same flow **3 times**: LandingVC --> LoginVC --> MainVC.

The results below:

[image]

*ps1: to get the results I used the "**Debug Navigator**" tab in xCode.*

[image]

To verify that no ViewController was dismissed during the whole flow I used the "View Memory Graph Hierarchy":

[image]

As you can see we have 3 instances of every ViewController I navigated through (by the way, MainVC is the MainTabBarController which is consisted of HomeViewController, FavouritesViewController, TrendingViewController, and SettingsViewController).

**QUESTION B:**
Is there a way I can deallocate [remove/pop/dismiss/etc] ViewControllers from memory but still have the same result?

**QUESTION C:**
Is it normal for the memory to increase from 55.4 MB to 68.1 MB following that flow?

ps2: All UI was built programmatically. No Storyboard involved.

Thanks in advance and sorry for the long post.

Comment: When you `present` a viewcontroller, do you always `dismiss` it as well? Replacing the `rootViewController` while still presenting a viewcontroller will lead to the presented one still remaining in the view hierarchy somewhere. You may try inspecting the view hierarchy using the button looking like three rectangles above the debugger window in Xcode.

Comment: No, I only dismiss the view controller when I move away from ForgotPasswordVC and back to LoginVC. As for the rest, I am using "present" 3 more times: 1 to go from LoginVC to MainVC, 1 to go from RegisterVC to MainVC and 1 to go from MainVC to LandingVC when user logs out. I think i cannot use dismiss() in neither cases. But then again maybe I am wrong. Regarding rootViewController, it is set before any viewController is presented (this is the reason I placed the code inside didFinishLaunchingWithOptions in appDelegate.swift). How would you approach this flow if someone asked you to build it?

Comment: `present` method is modal, which means that any modally presented VC must also be dismissed at some point, or the entire view stack beneath the presented VC will be kept.

Comment: I made some changes that help to mitigate the issue. First of all i am setting the MainVC as a rootViewController. Then I am deciding inside the MainVC whether the user is logged in or not. If not logged in, then I am presenting the LandingVC. From LandingVC I am pushing the LoginVC. If the credentials are correct then I dismiss() and the MainVC is in front again. The only issue with this approach is that the LoginVC stays in the memory since is pushed but never popped. Is there a way to pop LoginVC while dismissing all modally presented VCs?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uinavigationcontroller/1621855-poptorootviewcontroller

Comment: As soon as the user authenticates the credentials, if 
I use popToRootViewController(animated:) will only remove LoginVC and show the LandingVC, which is not the rootViewController. I want to show MainVC. I can do that if I use dismiss(). This will show the MainVC but the LoginVC will stay in the memory [while popToRootViewController will remove LoginVC from the memory]. What i want is a combination: As soon as the user is authenticated to go to MainVC and remove any viewController from memory.

Comment: You will need to use `pop` to remove any viewcontroller that has been `push`ed, and `dismiss` to remove any viewcontroller that has been `present`ed.

Comment: Thank you for all your answers. As it turns out the problem was not related to view controller presentation, but rather to retain cycle. You can check my question and answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51051838/swift-presenting-modally-and-dismissing-a-navigation-controller/51078752#51078752 if you are interested! Thanks again!